# Recover data from partition formatted through Android USB

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, mount, android

I formatted an sdcard with GParted through the USB share of an Android phone.

Neither the phone, nor the computer recognize the partitions on the sdcard anymore. When I share the sdcard through USB, the device appears as /dev/sdb, but fdisk doesn't recognize it.

Mount says:

```
#mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 -t auto /home/alex/tmp/mount1/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/mmcblk0p1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/mmcblk0p1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

How do I mount whatever is on the sdcard to recover my data? When I formatted the sdcard was presented as a block device at mount time, and I could clearly see the original FAT32, so I would assume a fs 
structure was preserved inside the /dev/mmcblk0p1 partition.

Output of file and fdisk:

```
# file /dev/mmcblk0
/dev/mmcblk0: block special (179/0)

# file /dev/mmcblk0p1 
/dev/mmcblk0p1: block special (179/1)

# fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 29.6 GiB, 31812747264 bytes, 62134272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device         Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1       8192 62134271 62126080 29.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


# fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0p1 
Disk /dev/mmcblk0p1: 29.6 GiB, 31808552960 bytes, 62126080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc38c655c

Device           Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1p1          2048 51193855 51191808 24.4G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/mmcblk0p1p2      51193856 62126079 10932224  5.2G 83 Linux
```

/dev/mmcblk0p1 appears to contain ~24.5 GiB vfat and ~5 GiB ext4. So I believe the conclusion would be that the sdcard contains what *should* be a 30 GiB vfat partition, but is really another block containing two partitions. This is entirely consistent with what I did, but I don't know how to get the data back.

Answer (score 0):

The fdisk output

```
Device           Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1p1          2048 51193855 51191808 24.4G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/mmcblk0p1p2      51193856 62126079 10932224  5.2G 83 Linux
```

confirms that what's supposed to be a partition is actually a block containing a formatted disk.

Mount accepts an offset as a parameter, so a quick approximation to get the size of a sector is 25 GiB divided by the number of sectors: 24.4 ⋅ 1024 ⋅ 1024 ⋅ 1024 / (51193855-2048) ≈ 511,78698. So the partition starts at byte 512 ⋅ 2048.
Mount the partition with correct offset, then back-up all the data and format the sdcard correctly with gparted:

```
# mount -t auto -o offset=1048576,ro /dev/mmcblk0p1 /home/alex/tmp/mount1/
```